# Jmeter 5.3: Parent HTTP request fails due to child request favicon.svg failed which has same domain

Tags: jmeter

We recorded UI script using Blazemeter and all HTTP requests having advanced settings 'Retrieve Embedded resources' checked as expected. When re-play the same script by importing in Jmeter, the parent HTTP request is downloading all embedded resources along with favicon.svg, however this .svg request always fails (both requests having same domain).

Is there any way to make parent node PASS though child request failed in Jmeter. URLs must match option of Advanced tab of HTTP request's can be used if different domain.

Please suggest.

Jmeter v: 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are in:

1. Remove this `favicon.svg` from the "embedded resources" scope:

   [image]

   this option is available since [JMeter 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65883520/what-is-the-difference-between-ramp-up-time-and-synchronization-timer/65885022#65885022) so you will have to upgrade
2. There is a [setting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) to ignore eventual failures of embedded resources retrieval, you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, able to get Parent request as PASS after adding the given line in user.properties file. Getting java-lang-nullpointerexception issue with 5.4 version hence not trying to upgrade https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65827396/jmeter-5-4-java-lang-nullpointerexception-in-thread-threadawt-eventqueue-0-6

Comment: sorry, corrected. Getting java-lang-nullpointerexception.